# How to set Google Analytics on my website which is created on DNN 6.3?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

How can we set Google Analytics on my website which is created on DNN 6.3.
Is there any need to install google analytics module in DNN 6.3 (I think it is already inbuilt in upper version of DNN 6.0) or it just start working by only set Tracking Id in admin section.

Actually what i did :> I have created an account with "Google Analytics" & set our site parameters after that I got Tracking Id which I have set to my DNN account.
Now what i had seen on my Google Analytics account there was no counting of any report all are showing zero. But during that time i was visit more than 5 times on my website.

So if anyone have an idea what i was doing wrong kindly suggest to me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as DNN 6.3. It went from 6.2.x to 7.0.x... But, you don't need to install any additional modules for DNN 6.x to get Google Analytics to show up. You just need to enter your Tracking ID in Admin -> Google Analytics.

Then you can check whether it's working correctly by verifying it rendered in the HTML. Bring up your site in your browser and then view the source of the page. Then search for "UA-". If it finds it, then that should be the Google Analytics snippet. If it didn't find it, then there's something going wrong.

Keep in mind that by default Google Analytics won't show the current day's hits. You have to modify the date range to include todays date.

Comment: Exactly 100% right ! Thanks a lot for your answer but I have done this before your answer but anyway this is the correct answer. Always keeps helping to others by this Blog such as me.

Comment: How does this work when u have multiple portals setup?
The only option would be to put the tracking code in the themes footer.

Comment: No, the admin section is specific to each portal. It works fine for multi-portal installs.

Comment: Hi EfficionDave. I have got this issue. I check html code and it contains google analytics script but there is no counting in google analytics admin page. Please check my site: http://www.bodytshirt.com. is it wrong anything?

Comment: I also check script gave by google and render script by DNN. It not equal. So should i adding script from google manually?